# SonarQube Run scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have success log:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 29.282s
INFO: Final Memory: 15M/64M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But nothing statistics in dashboard, but have error message

```
The main branch has no lines of code.
```

My properties

```
sonar.projectKey=....
sonar.sources=base/
```

My project:

```
root_dir
---------- sonar-project.properties
---------- base (in this dir file for scan)
```

and have this log

```
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
```

Comment: Try adding wildcards e.g. base/*

Have a look at the following page for details of supported patterns: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/